# Colours in GeoTIFFs

Tags: qgis, geotiff-tiff, multi-band

Coming from a somewhat "Photoshop" background, I am having trouble understanding how colouring/visualization works in QGIS.

When I import a GeoTIFF I get min and max clip values in the 3 basic channels and changing those values dramatically change the way the final image looks.

Why is that?  Could you refer me to a link that explains that?

Answer (score 1):

The corresponding QGIS documentation is at https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_raster/raster_properties.html.

> With the multiband color renderer, three selected bands from the image
> will be used as the red, green or blue component of the color image.
> QGIS automatically fetches Min and Max values for each band of the
> raster and scales the coloring accordingly.

The MinMax stretch means that the minimum value of each band of the raster image will be rendered as 0 and the maximum value will be rendered as 255. You should get the same result with Photoshop by using the Levels tool and setting the white point and black point https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/levels-adjustment.html.

To adjust the shadows and highlights manually, drag the black and white Input Levels sliders to the edge of the first group of pixels at either end of the histogram.

> For example, if you move the black point slider to the right at level
> 5, Photoshop maps all the pixels at level 5 and lower to level 0.
> Similarly, if you move the white point slider to the left at level
> 243, Photoshop maps all pixels at level 243 and higher to level 255.
> The mapping affects the darkest and lightest pixels in each channel.
> The corresponding pixels in the other channels are adjusted
> proportionately to avoid altering the color balance.